# Vim adventures level 8 shoot for the moon puzzle

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm a little stuck on level 8 of vim adventures with the shoot the moon puzzle. I've removed the bottom 3 lines with dG and also done  a replace at the top.

what I'm left with is "shoot for the moon, even if you miss, you'll **have a** land among the **stone pill** ars."

(bold parts are the text to delete).

I've tried everything like attempting to delete with dw, dW, db, dB, de, dE, pressing x repeatedly but no luck.

Could I have missed something out?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't played this level, but can you use the <kbd>t</kbd> motion at this point? If so, you could position the cursor at the beginning of `have a` and use <kbd>dtl</kbd> to delete to the next `l`. (Likewise with `one pill` and <kbd>dta</kbd>)